# Eclipse Regex find/replace

Tags: regex, eclipse

I want to replace the below string

```
String str = "sqi";
```

with

```
String str = "siq;
```

Can anyone help me finding a way to approach?

Comment: Why do you want to do that with a regex ? Cannot a simple String.replace suffice ?

Comment: `String str = "sqi"; str = "siq";`? :)

Comment: While at it, replace it with a [constant](http://java.about.com/od/understandingdatatypes/a/Using-Constants.htm) to save this hassle in the future.

Comment: First, eclipse is not a programming language. Did you mean java? Are you really asking how to do a search&replace in an editor? If so, then how is regex related? Second, there's a typo in the second example. We can fix that, but you shouldn't do it in the first place. Third, the question is extremely vague and ambiguous. One example does not constitute a specification. If it did, sp00m's comment would be a valid answer. Fourth, please show some effort please. There are surely plenty of dupes on SO (depending on what you want), regex tutorials, good regex tutorials... that you could have found.

Comment: reopen+1 - i know the answer, eclipse is an IDE and therefore not offtopic.

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>STRG</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) to open the "Find/Replace" window in Eclipse.